# memory allocation for static singleton class object

Tags: c++

For below singleton class where would be the memory taken from (Stack or Global memroy)

```
class Singleton
{
    public:

        static Singleton* get()
        {
            static Singleton instance;
            return &instance;
        }
};
```

Comment: Take care if you use multithreaded program. You should protect your static call.

Comment: i am more interested in singleton class memory allocation ,not for the static variable's memory allocation ..as i have seen in above link ..

Comment: @Ashwin actually, this is guaranteed to be thread-safe

Comment: I don't understand why you are returning a pointer: if it cannot be null, it should be a **reference**.

Answer (score 3):

`instance` will be located in static storage (or global as you call it).